# Trying to install tp-link archer T2U wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I've just installed Ubuntu and I would like to get my USB wifi adapter working.

Is there anyone who knows where I can get the right drivers for this?

output of `lsusb`

```
 Bus 002 Device 004: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
 Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
 Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
 Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c21c Suyin Corp. 
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsusb` with the wifi adapter plugged in. Thank you.

Comment: Your usb adaptor appears to be Bus 002 Device 004: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp - This corresponds to a mediatek chip. Mediateks' download page is here: http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/ although I can't find anything further of use other than the rumoured driver for that adaptor is called mt7650u_sta.

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: There *are* official sources for the drivers - as noted by some other answer here - but those don't (usually(?)) compile/work out of the box. 
Also, the newest version doesn't work for me (Debian 8 with standard x64 kernel:
`3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
) - what *does* (still) work for me is commit   `4606187110b323c272aed504144ee759b31af8ac`.

There is an easier solution than trying to use the manufacturer's source (taken from [this (German) site](http://www.myria.de/computer/1308-tp-link-archer-t2u-ac600-unter-linux-nutzen)):

Just run (with the device being unplugged)

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

and reboot. As indicated above, you might want to `git checkout 4606187110b323c272aed504144ee759b31af8ac` before running `make` and `make install`. For instance, the newest version

- Caused it to freeze

  Didn't integrate with NetworkManager, ...

and who knows what else.

Worked for me, I also have the Archer T2U, with the same USB-device. I run another system ( I used this with LMDE, kernel 3.11, now I'm on Debian (see above)), however the solution I have linked was tried with the following setups:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, linux kernel 3.13.0.49, gcc 4.8.2

  Ubuntu 15.04, linux kernel 3.19.0-15, gcc 4.9.2

So there might be a good chance, that this will work for you.

The author(s) simply modified the MT7610U linux driver from the MediaTek homepage to compile for your device as well as a couple of other ones based on the same chipset.
If you feel like it, you can probably run some command to diff the linked source and the one from MediaTek since directory trees and source file are probably no different from the MediaTek source.

UPDATE: There is another site that may be helpful, if you want to go into fixing the original source yourself instead of following the above instructions:
http://hprath.com/2014/06/cisco-linksys-ae6000-ac580-media-tek-mt7610u-mt7630u-mt7650u-linux-x64-driver-patch/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The solution depends on the availability of a certain git repository. The same argument you are giving could be given about any solution referring to some online resource. Yet, it wouldn't make sense to downvote every answer referring to online resources that could change, would it?

Comment: I have, however included the commands themselves here. It's obviously more convenient this way if you don't know any German.

Comment: I can confirm this works on 15.04, 3.19.0-18-lowlatency, gcc 4.9.2, 64-bit.

Comment: There's a typo in the url of the git repo.  There should not be a space in Myria-de.

Comment: I just tried this with an exact Ubuntu 15.04, identical kernel, using the commit you are referring to. No luck. I am seeing lots of "RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110)" errors, which is exactly the problem I had with some ~10 different versions of the drivers and any kernel in between 2.6.x and 4.9.x. Somewhat frustrating. Just to make sure, my device says 148f:761a and should be a https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3):

There is now a linux driver for this device on the TP-LINK website: http://www.tp-link.com/lb/download/Archer-T2U_V1.html#Driver

Comment: For anybody looking to use this device on Linux recently, don't bother with the official drivers. They are for a very outdated kernel and the instructions look like they were written in Chinese and put into Google Translate. I had moderate success with dkms and [these](https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes) drivers after running `sudo service network-manager restart`, but after a few months the driver started to freeze the system unless the adapter was unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

**This device currently does not work with linux.**

The [MediaTek MT7610 USB driver](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/mt7610u-usb/) is the closest match for this device, however as of version **3.0.0.4_20130913** it does not directly support the T2U. I added the USB ID of the T2U to the driver, which allowed me to find networks but not to connect to any one of them. It looks like receiving of packets works, but sending or some part of network association fails.

Unfortunately, I had no success with [ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) either. The suggested method is to get ndiswrapper installed, add the XP driver, and use that:

```
apt-get install ndiswrapper-source ndisgtk
dkms autoinstall ndiswrapper
ndiswrapper -i Driver\ Files/Windows\ XP\ 64bit/RT2870.inf
modprobe ndiswrapper
```

However, both the driver supplied on CD-ROM and the [official 140523 download](http://www.tp-link.com.de/resources/software/Archer_T2U_V1_Driver_140523.zip) fails to load with ndiswrapper on a 64-bit machine:

```
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'ExEventObjectType'
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'__chkstk'
ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'rt2870'
ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver rt2870; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
```

This approach might work for you on 32-bit Linux, or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Pavilion 360 notebook. The solution above with the code (given), worked for me, too. The signal seems weak for the moment, but stable. I will test it in the upcoming weeks:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make clean
make
sudo make install
```