# TP-Link Archer T2U does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

I have a TP-Link Archer T2U that I want to use on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (kernel 4.4.0.31-generic). I downloaded the Linux driver from the TP-Link website (http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T2U.html#Driver), but unfortunately they say on their website it only works for kernel versions 2.6~3.16. I tried my luck anyway, but alas, it does not work.

Has anyone been able to get it to work on kernel versions later than 4 ?

I tried their suggested installation :
(1) sudo make

---

Output of sudo make:

```
$ sudo make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL'
/bin/sh cp_util.sh

make -C MODULE/ build_tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE'
make -C tools
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/tools'
/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7650u
chipset = mt7630u
chipset = mt7610u
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE'
make -C MODULE/ osdrv
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7053:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
^
/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7053:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
^
/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_private_get_statistics’:
/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:9737:17: warning: unused variable ‘fec_coding’ [-Wunused-variable]
    static char *fec_coding[2] = {"bcc", "ldpc"};
                 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1403: recipe for target '_module_/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
Makefile:548: recipe for target 'osdrv' failed
make[1]: *** [osdrv] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/werner/Downloads/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/MODULE'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
******
```

So clearly this is not working for me. I desperately need this to work.

I also ran lsusb, but it doesn't seem as if my system even picks up the device ****

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID abcd:1234 Unknown 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c063 Logitech, Inc. DELL Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
****
```

Any ideas ?

I already looked at the following pages, and tried some of the suggestions there, but nothing seems to work:

[TP-Link Archer T2U installing driver issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730933/tp-link-archer-t2u-installing-driver-issue)

[Trying to install tp-link archer T2U on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499091/trying-to-install-tp-link-archer-t2u-on-ubuntu)

[TP-Link Archer T2U does not work on Ubuntu 15.10 +](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752084/tp-link-archer-t2u-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Edit the question to add the info

Comment: Did you also try the instructions in my answer to [Trying to install tp-link archer T2U on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499091/trying-to-install-tp-link-archer-t2u-on-ubuntu)? Especially with checking out the older commit before installing the driver (and if that failed, the other possibilities)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing

lsusb 'can' see your device, from your lsusb output above:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

You can get rid of your build errors by editing the config.mk file(s)
The one that looks like it's failing for you in in ~/MODULE/os/linux/.

Edit the config.mk file in that folder, appending the following to the FLAGS to the compiler. ( approx line 235 ).

```
-Wno-error=date-time
```

so that it looks something like this:

```
WFLAGS := -g -DAGGREGATION_SUPPORT -DPIGGYBACK_SUPPORT -DWMM_SUPPORT -DLINUX -Wall 
-Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types 
-Wno-error=date-time**
```

Good luck

I had issues with pointer types so I needed to add the other one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Before 4.13 kernel this drivers works good [Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916](https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git) but on new gcc give an error when i try to make. 
Now I search for solution agan and [archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer](https://github.com/ivannieto/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer), making without errors. ra0 is work stable on 16.04 + HWE.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your card but if you have not already try disabling secure boot from your bios, I would do so. I got a HP Stream working with Ubuntu by doing so maybe it will help you out. The driver was up to kernel 3.16 as well, I hope this helps.

Other than that, your driver appears to have failed being created. AS far as I can see two errors were produce that is keeping your driver from being compiled.

If push comes to shove, you might have to modify the code to make this drover work.

I spotted two errors, A time Marco and Date Marco that prevents your Driver from being created. their is a unsed variable somewhere probalbly causeing a warning.I believe those two things are keeping your driver from being created.

I Wonder if it's possible for a person to modify the code without owning the card?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more fresh drivers for this stuff:

- https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes
- https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u
- https://github.com/Hygens/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610